# Can't get multiple prefixes to work with discord.js. How can I rewrite this so that it recognizes both prefixes?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots, prefix, prefixes

the title is pretty self-explanatory. Tried messing around with diff iterations of the below code. This version recognizes firstPrefix, but not secondPrefix. I just want my djs bot to be able to recognize both prefixes and run the Args split accordingly.

```
const firstPrefix = '!test ';
const secondPrefix = '!testtwo ';

//Prefix
bot.on('message', message => {
    message.content = message.content.toLowerCase();
    if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(firstPrefix || secondPrefix))  {
        return;
    }

//Args split
    if (message.content.startsWith(firstPrefix)) {
        console.log("A")
        var args = message.content.slice(firstPrefix.length).split(/ +/);
    }
    else if (message.content.startsWith(secondPrefix)) {
        console.log("B")
        var args = message.content.slice(secondPrefix.length).split(/ +/);
    }
```

I've tried doing:

```
if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(firstPrefix) || !message.content.startsWith(secondPrefix))
```

But that didn't work at all. Pretty stumped here, any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code (second code block) will not work, as if it starts with one prefix, it does not start with the other prefix, causing it to result in a true if statement, and does not execute your command.

In the first code block, since both `firstPrefix` and `secondPrefix` are defined with values, `firstPrefix || secondPrefix` will evaluate to `firstPrefix`.

Since you want to include both `firstPrefix` **AND** `secondPrefix`, you should do something like this:

```js
if (
  message.author.bot || /* if it is a bot */
  (!message.content.startsWith(firstPrefix) && /* does not start with first */
  !message.content.startsWith(secondPrefix))) /* and does not start with second */ {
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your prefixes in an array, then check if the content starts with either prefix using [Array#some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
const prefixes = ['!test ', '!testtwo '];

bot.on('message', message => {
   ...
   if (prefixes.some(prefix => message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
      ...
   }
});
```